# I cannnot name my solana token created with spl-token cli

Tags: spl-token, token, solana-cli

I have created a new fresh token in the terminal with the spl-token creator

```
MacBook-Pro token-vesting % spl-token create-token

Creating token F2Ty85DNzwXYfVaHhnBGCvmJyzRU9tZiDfJPYJMAc57h

MacBook-Pro token-vesting % spl-token create-account F2Ty85DNzwXYfVaHhnBGCvmJyzRU9tZiDfJPYJMAc57h

Creating account GDV7f2RbQHuatxQsm6C4HfRSCsDTMgrkauVx6b6Gg6V
```

After this I mint some tokens.

The problem comes when I try to add a name to my token.

The token can be found here: https://explorer.solana.com/address/F2Ty85DNzwXYfVaHhnBGCvmJyzRU9tZiDfJPYJMAc57h?cluster=devnet

The mint Mint Authority
7S2wLjcLABoh1ozbBRWVTDqu56TUudgmhwEc2P9KXdGB is to my wallet

which I import in Sollet and try first to add the name here:
https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/update

but I got error: "WalletSendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3f"

I have also wrote node script with @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata
to try to name the token but the result is the same.

I`ve found the kind of the error '0x3f' is "#[error("Account does not support specified authority type")]"

what is wrong with the authority when I always try with the same account which can minth the token and can transfer it but is not able to name it.